# Use img2pdf in batch command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-line-arguments, img2pdf

I have been looking for some time for a solution to a "very simple" question.
I created a batch file (under windows) which allows me to download a set of images. I would just like to merge these images into a PDF (image 1: page 1, image 2: page 2 etc ...).
I am using (for shell) the excellent [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) package and it works great!

So under windows I do the same: I download (with python and pip) the package and I give it this command (exactly the same under shell):

```
img2pdf *.jpg -o FILE.pdf
```

Unfortunately it does not recognize the `*.jpg` (which stands for "all files with a .jpg extension").

I would like to point out that, of course, my files are in *.jpg* and that the package works perfectly because with one file (`img2pdf 1.jpg -o FILE.pdf`) it does the job.

How then to make him understand that?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: I guess you are looking for the [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html): `for %I in ("*.jpg") do img2pdf "%~I.jpg" -o "%~nxI.pdf"` (double the `%`-symbols in a batch file)…

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yes I tried but unfortunately it creates one PDF file per image and not the merger of all the images into one PDF.

Comment: Sorry, I overread "merge". I don't know `img2pdf` and whether it supports merging, so I'm afraid I can't help; what does its documentation say?

Comment: No problem ! Thank you ;)

Actually the package was not developed for windows, but it works under python so I tried to embed it in a batch file and it works for a file assembly like this:
`img2pdf 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -o FILE.pdf` but not with all the files in the folder!

Comment: I know the number of files in the folder, maybe is it possible to include it in a count?
Like this: `1->% FILES% .jpg`

Comment: You could build a list of files first, like `set "LIST=" & for %%I in ("*.jpg") do set "LIST=!LIST! "%%I""`, when [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, and then do `img2pdf !LIST! -o "FILE.pdf"`…

Comment: Oh great idea! I tried immediately. Unfortunately here is the output:
`img2pdf: error: infile argument: "! LIST!" does not exist` and if I do `echo %LIST%` => `!LIST! "10.JPG"` (print the lastest file)

Comment: As I already said you **must enable delayed expansion**! put `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` on top of your script for that…

Comment: Apologies indeed I had not taken this into account! 

Thank you very much @aschipfl for your help and your solution!
Should you post it as an answer to my question if I'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `img2pdf` does not support wildcards, but it might support a list of files:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Build a space-separated list of quoted file names:
set "LIST=" & for %%I in ("*.jpg") do set "LIST=!LIST! "%%I""
rem // Provide the built list as arguments to the tool:
img2pdf !LIST! -o "FILE.pdf"
endlocal
```